# Увидел в окно/в окне лес. Как правильно?

Tags: грамматика, морфология, предлоги, управление, существительные

Увидел в окно или увидел в окне? В нац корпусе оба варианта встречаются: в окно (примерно 30 раз), в окне (примерно 45 раз). А с точки зрения грамматики есть какая-нибудь причина писать или так или так? Может, предпочтение падежному вопросу синтаксического или рекомендации по управлению глагола и т.п...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь в книге "Управление в русском языке" говорит следующее:

> **видеть** — во что и в чем.
>
> 1. **во что** (в значении "смотреть"). Идя к двери, Мересьев видел в
>      зеркало, как члены комиссии о чем-то оживленно переговаривались 
>      (Б. Полевой). В левый иллюминатор вижу антенну, в правый — Землю (из
>      газет).
> 2. **в чем** ( в значении "увидеть" ). Но такого странного
>      выражения, какое инструктор видел в зеркале на лице этого красивого
>      деле, ни разу не доводилось наблюдать (Б.Полевой). В правом
>      иллюминаторе вижу полет частиц (из газет).

Следовательно, допустимы оба варианта. В некоторых случаях может быть предпочтителен один из вариантов — в зависимости от контекста или авторского замысла.

Answer (score 2):

Сравните: посмотрел в окно и увидел лес (увидел в окно лес); посмотрел в сторону окна и увидел лес (увидел в окне лес).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Солнце **в окне** как раз опускалось в тайгу, которая начиналась сразу за огородом. [Виктор Ремизов. Воля вольная // «Новый мир», 2013]

Я успел заметить **в окне** стоящий на палубе серый военный самолет с двумя двигателями под крыльями ― вроде того, на котором президент Буш садился на авианосец после падения Багдада. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

(Очевидно, он не смотрел специально в окно, а только бросил взгляд в сторону окна.)

Появился Олег ― он увидел их **в окно**. [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]

(Олег смотрел в окно и увидел их.)

Через пять минут он должен был встретиться с Кларой, она уже прошла от вахты по двору, он видел **в окно**. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

(Он смотрел в окно и видел Клару.)

Дополнение

Среди тех 45 вхождений "в окне", о которых Вы говорите, большинство описывает ситуацию, противоположную Вашей, там смотрят **с улицы** и видят что-то в окне дома, как в рамке.